# Highstock \ Highcharts. Combine line and percentage charts?

Tags: highcharts, line, percentage

How to combine in one area `line-chart` and `percentage-chart` like on the picture [Picture URL](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1b9Ow2tXL4Scu4kbc__5LJ45x_hTWF_VM). Both charts with the same data.

Answer (score 0):

The solution in another [forum](https://forum.highcharts.com/post138422.html#p138422)

You need to create another yAxis and set its position by top property. It is also important to set height to axes be displayed correctly.

```
yAxis: [{
   height: 200
},{
   height: 160,
   top: 325
}]
```

To the data be presented as a percentage, set stacking to "percent" on the proper series.

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dL1zj7jz/)

[https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/yAxis.height](http://API%20Reference%201)

https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/yAxis.top

https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.area.stacking